# Batch Neo4J transaction batch

Tags: neo4j, transactions, py2neo

I'm trying to create large graphs with py2neo (v3). I am using transactions to be able to rollback any changes in case of errors.

However, the error that is causing rollbacks is that Java is running out of memory (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space) not really the intended result :)

Is there any way to use a transaction and batch it? I've seen that the Transaction class has a process() method, but it is unclear to me what it does.

Regards

Comment: You should do the batch in your code : create a counter and when you reach you the batch size, commit and recreate the transaction. Otherwise you can also use some `APOC` procedure for commit (https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_commit)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is there any way to track the amount of queries in the transaction?